# Error writing lock file: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, permission-denied, nas, swapfile

After connecting my NAS drive with the mount command in the nashome directory,
the following error occurs, when trying to edit or create any file in the mounted directory tree:
`[ Error writing lock file ./.index.html.swp: Permission denied ]`
[Error Message when trying to edit the index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csf7h.png)

I also tried editing the files as a root, however the same error occurs.

The permissions in the parent directory of the file are as follows:
[permissions to the index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjNix.png)

Is there anyone who can explain what is happening?

I already tried deleting the nashome directory and unmounting the NAS drive and then remounting it again.
However, with no effect.

Comment: This question appears to be about professional system & network administration -- this would be a better fit to be a question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, follow these steps.

If you're using Ubuntu:

1. Launch the native Disks software on your system.
2. Identify and choose the specific disk and partition associated with the current file path.
3. Access the "Settings" and proceed to "Edit Mount Options."
4. Make sure to select the button option labeled "User Session Defaults."
5. With these changes applied, proceed to remount the disk.

Once the disk is remounted, attempt the task again to see if the issue has been successfully resolved.

I hope I've helped.